# One class "uses" another class in Java? Implementing "uses-a" class

Tags: java, class

How do we "use" a class(Class-1) in another class(Class-2),given that Class-1 contains only attributes and corresponding get functions and set functions,and Class-2 has all the manipulating functions(which were previously belonging to Class-1) and uses Class-1 attributes?

Final Objective is to create a standalone Class-1---in a separate file--- with only attributes,setters and getters and a Class-2---in a different file--- that contains all the methods of Class-1. Assume Class 2 imports class 1,and only Class-2 objects are created in the main[or calling] function.

One method is to declare an object of Class-1 in Class-2, and then using that object's attributes and get-set functions,but as I've read in https://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/ClassesObjects1.html , that method is "has-a" class,not "use-a" class.

So how to implement "use-a" class?
Please refer https://www.artima.com/objectsandjava/webuscript/ClassesObjects1.html for more clarity.

Comment: What's the point in "has-a" if you don't "use-a"?

Comment: @AndyTurner, Hadn't thought about that before, but I think there is a difference.  Class A _has a_ B if class A has a _field_ of type B.  Class A _uses_ type B if at least one method of class A performs operations on a value/object of type B.  Thing is, neither of those two relationships requires the other to be true.  An `A` could expose a public getter and setter for a value of type B, but never perform any operation on the B value, and a method of class `A` could operate on B values that it obtains from some place other than one of its own fields.

Comment: See @jameslarge. Do you think extending would be a good idea in that case? If you aren't using it, why depend on it? I understand what you mean though. I would say it depends on the entire system design. Stylistically, probably not the best idea on the planet.

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks for replying,but please see the edit made after your comment. In this case,if using a "use-a" structure,wouldn't we have to declare an object of Class-1 in Class-2's every time we call it? Would the changes in attribute be permanent? Or,are u saying a "use-a" structure REQUIRES a "has-a"?

Comment: There is no way ever to "use-a" Class-1 if only Class-2 objects are ever created, because there is no Class-1 instance available to be used.

Comment: @DebosmitRay,Again,thank you for sharing your opinion. My first reaction was the same. But,as you mentioned,that system design will be called a "is-a" structure, whereby,Class-2 is a specific version of Class-1! So,still not an implementation of "use-a".

Comment: @JohnBollinger,please see the edit,sorry for not clarifying further.Class-1 objects are just not created in the calling[or main] function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we "use" a class(Class-1) in another class(Class-2),given that Class-1 contains only attributes and corresponding get functions and set functions,and Class-2 has all the manipulating functions(which were previously belonging to Class-1) and uses Class-1 attributes?

If Class-2 does not *have* any Class-1, then the only ways it can *use* one at any given point is if it creates one, or if it has one provided to it.  However it obtains an instance, it can query and manipulate that instance's state, and it can pass that instance to other objects.  No other use is possible, because that's the full extent of what anyone can do with Class-1 instances.

When you say "only Class-2 objects are created in the main[or calling] function", I interpret you to mean that whoever invokes Class-2's methods never has any Class-1 instance to provide.  In particular, I assume you are not drawing an imaginary line between the user creating an instance of Class-1 directly and the user obtaining one indirectly, such as via Class-2.  Such a distinction is pointless.  If Class-2 creates instances of Class-1 on behalf of its user and provides them to its user, then the user has effectively created them.  If the user can obtain Class-1 instances *by any means*, then the details of those means are irrelevant at the level of abstraction of the question.

That leaves only the possibility that Class-2 "uses" Class-1 instances that it creates itself as needed, that it references only via local variables and / or method parameters (because it does not "have" any Class-1), and that it does not permit to be exposed to its user.  This is certainly possible, but it has limited utility.  If that design works, then Class-1 could be removed entirely, replaced with local variables and method parameters of Class-2.  It seems unlikely that such a design would serve, however, given that the original single-class design did have state.  Still, it's possible.

Note also that if Class-2 does not *have* a particular Class-1 instance, then the only way it can be limited to *use* only a particular Class-1 instance is if the use is limited to some event that can happen only once in a Class-2 instances lifetime, such as its initialization.  Otherwise, it's not a "uses *a*" relationship, but rather a *uses* relationship.

Inasmuch as the original design had both state and behavior, it seems unlikely that the state part can simply be dispensed with.  In that case, the constraint that the Class-2 user not create any Class-1 instances seems wrong-headed.  You could perhaps work around it by creating another class that maintains the same state that Class-1 does, but that's absurd.  Why create a new class when there's a perfectly good one already available?  If you simply want to avoid Class-1 being instantiated directly by classes other than Class-2, then allow Class-2 to provide instances of Class-1 to its user.  Since the user can then obtain instances, it can feed them back to Class-2 as method arguments.  That allows Class-2 to use Class-1 without having any Class-1 of its own.  For example,

```
public class State {
    private int x;

    State(int x) {  // package-private
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

public class Behavior {
    // Uses State, but is not a State and does not have a State

    public State doSomethingThatYieldsState(String s) {
        try {
            return new State(Integer.parseInt(s));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int doSomethingWithState(State s, int y) {
        return y + s.getX();
    }

    public void doSomethingToState(State s) {
        s.setX(s.getX() + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is one way to think about it. Square is a child of Rectangle and Rectangle is a child of Shape. In a case like this, the following will give you an idea about the architecture. Note that although I have called `Shape` an abstract class, since it does not implement any of the functions, it is a good idea to use it as an interface.

More so, think about it this way. We were thinking about doing square/rectangle. What if the Shape was a Circle? Could we really depend on the implementation of the area() function in Shape?

*[Please note that this is not compiled and I haven't written Java in a while. So, please excuse syntactical errors. I hope to have gotten my point across.]*

So maybe, this is something our Shape could look like(?)

public <s>abstract class</s> interface Shape

```
public interface Shape {
    public abstract double area();
    public abstract double perimeter();
}
```

Circle could do something like this..

```
/* You might need to import the Math.. thing here 
   Note: Circle implements Shape, not extends, 
   since Shape is an interface. */
public class Circle implements Shape {
    private final double rad;
    private final double PI = Math.PI;

    public Circle(double rad) {
        this.rad = rad;
    }

    public double area() {
        return PI * Math.pow(rad, 2);
    }

    public double perimeter() {
        return 2 * PI * rad;
    }
}
```

Now, let us get `Rectangle`.

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private final double WIDTH, HEIGHT; 

    public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        this.WIDTH = width;
        this.HEIGHT = height;
    }

    public double area() {
        return this.WIDTH * this.HEIGHT;
    }

    public double perimeter() {
        return 2 * (this.WIDTH + this.HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

If you think about it, a `Square` is a specialized case of `Rectangle`. It makes sense to (maybe) utilize some `Rectangle` properties in `Square`.

```
public class Square extends Rectangle {

    // already have width, height in Rectangle 

    public Square(double side) {
        super(side, side);
    }

    // note that you do not need area 
    // and perimeter any more since Rectangle
    // has them implemented
    /* You could of course do something like this..
       public double area() {
           return super.area();
       }
    */
}
```

Now, to wrap up. `"has-a" vs "use-a"`. If `Square` did not use `Rectangle` stuff, it wouldn't really need to extend from it now, would it? Maybe implementing `Shape` would be good enough. Say, `Square` had the field `side` defined in it. Well, in that case, would it be worth having `Rectangle`? I think this will give you an idea. The rest is completely dependent on your implementation. If you have a bunch of these kinds of things going on, maybe think about a redesign. I think one rare occurrence of something like this could be forgivable. You'll be the best judge.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to answer. i totally agree that an inheritance is the straight-forward method to go.But like u said, my implementation requires me to put inheritance out of the question! A manipulation of Objects is needed and a "uses" implementation using objects is required!

Comment: Re squares and rectangles:  Your `Square` class and your `Rectangle` class are immutable.  OK, no problems there, but google for "square rectangle problem" or "circle ellipse problem" to find out why a _mutable_ square is _not_ a kind of mutable rectangle.  The examples may sound contrived, but there really is a lot of software out there that turns ugly when somebody tries to extend a design that relies on an inappropriate "is a" relationship.

Comment: @jameslarge Totally with you on that one. I left that out somewhat intentionally to keep the answer concise and reader-friendly. I'm assuming you are venturing on ideas along the lines of where a bunch of stuff written for `Square` would fail on `Rectangle` simply because **it is** a new Shape, and not a *renamed/recycled* Rectangle. A good way to think about this could also be something like `do you want to recycle this object or would it be a much better choice to create a new one?`.

Comment: @DeeJay You would want to read the last 2 comments.

Comment: @DebosmitRay, just did,and it helped! :)